# Converting cshtml to vbhtml

Tags: razor

I am converting a Partial View created using C# to VB, and need some assistance converting the below source code snippet,

```html
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm", @class = "navbar-right" }))
    {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">
        <li>
            @Html.ActionLink("Hello " + User.Identity.GetUserName() + "!", "Manage", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
        </li>
        <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></li>
    </ul>
    }
}
else
{
    <ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink" })</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })</li>
    </ul>
}
```

I am receiving the below Parse Error Message 
 "class" is a reserved word and cannot be used in implicit expressions.  An explicit expression ("@()") must be used.

Answer (score 1):

Citing [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-vb#visual-basic-language-and-syntax):

> In server code blocks, you'll often want to output text and markup to the page. If a server code block contains text that's not code and that instead should be rendered as is, ASP.NET needs to be able to distinguish that text from code. For example:

```
@If IsPost Then
    ' This line has all content between matched <p> tags.
    @<p>Hello, the time is @DateTime.Now and this page is a postback!</p> 
Else
    ' All content between matched tags, followed by server code.
    @<p>Hello, <em>Stranger!</em> today is: </p> @DateTime.Now
End If
```

Here's your code converted:

```
@Imports Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
@If Request.IsAuthenticated Then
    Using Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, New With {.id = "logoutForm", .class = "navbar-right"})
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        @<ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Hello " & User.Identity.GetUserName() & "!", "Manage", "Account", routeValues:=Nothing, htmlAttributes:=New With {Key .title = "Manage"})</li>
            <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></li>
        </ul>
    End Using
Else
    @<ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account", routeValues:=Nothing, htmlAttributes:=New With {Key .id = "registerLink"})</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", routeValues:=Nothing, htmlAttributes:=New With {Key .id = "loginLink"})</li>
    </ul>
End If
```